# existe alguma forma de fechar uma aba do navegador com javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um script que só funciona localmente. Existe alguma maneira de fechar a aba do navegador usando `javascript`? Se sim, poderiam dar exemplos?

Answer (score 5):

Use o [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close). Ele fecha a aba/janela atual.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.close()" value="Fechar janela" />

<button onclick="window.close()">Fechar janela</button>

<a href="javascript:void()" onclick="window.close()">Fechar janela</a>
```

Javascript puro:

```
document.getElementById("#botaoOuLink").onclick = function()
{
    window.close();
}
```

Com jQuery:

```
$(elemento).on("click", function() 
{
    window.close();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Encontrei o mesmo problema e resolvi usando:

```
window.frames.closewindow();
```

Pelo pouco que estudei vi que o javascript só consegue fechar janelas com `window.close()`, quando você abre elas através de comando javascript, logo, esse código postado acima acessa o "container" de frames e fecha ele.

Isto porque trabalho com um sistema baseado em frames, não fiz o teste com outro tipo de sistema. 
Vale a pena testar.

Answer (score 1):

Função Javascript para fechamento:

Caso queira que o usuário confirme a saída da página:

```
function close_window() {
  if (confirm("Fechar Janela?")) {
    close();
  }
}
```

Caso não:

```
function close_window() {
    close();
}
```

Com HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:close_window();">Fechar Janela</a>
```

ou

```
<a href="#" onclick="close_window();return false;">Fechar Janela</a>
```

Resposta original: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Comment: A pergunta original pede por confirmação. Essa pergunta não.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown adicionado

Comment: @Ricardo nesse caso eu fecho a atual, teria alguma ideia de como fechar todas menos a atual?