# Como fechar o separador com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Bom a minha pergunta é a seguinte, existe algum código javascript, que faça fechar automaticamente a aba que está aberta naquela página?

Ou seja eu entro com uma aba do meu navegador na página oi.html, existe algum código que faça fechar a aba automaticamente?

Obrigado.

Comment: Duplicata de [Fechar aba do Mozilla, IE, Chrome](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17401/70) e de [Existe alguma forma de fechar uma aba do navegador com javascript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75140/70)

Answer (score 0):

Gonçalo, poderás utilizar a função do javascript:

```
window.close();
```

Com isto consegues fechar o separador atual.